# Modifying the legends of MATLAB antenna pattern plot

Tags: matlab

```
ULAarray10 = phased.ULA('NumElements',2,'ElementSpacing',0.5);
ULAarray20 = phased.ULA('NumElements',4,'ElementSpacing',0.5);
fc = 1e9;
pattern(ULAarray10, fc)
hold on
pattern(ULAarray20, fc)

patternElevation(ULAarray10, fc, 90)
hold on
patternElevation(ULAarray20, fc, 90)
```

Here is some code that I have. I am wondering how can I modify the text in the legend of the pattern plot.

Comment: What is the code output? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code gives:

[image]

---

You can either call [`legend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html) to overwrite it.

```
legend('foo','bar');
```

or get the handle of the legend and modify its string. i.e.

```
hL = findobj(gcf, 'Type', 'Legend');
hL.String = {'foo', 'bar'};
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as I typed in the following code: ```patternElevation(ULAarray1, fc, 90)
hold on
patternElevation(ULAarray2, fc, 90)
hold on
patternElevation(ULAarray3, fc, 90)
legend('Spacing = 0.1', 'Spacing = 0.25', 'Spacing = 0.5')```                                                     It turns me a series of warnings and error:          Warning: Error executing listener callback for PostSet event on DisplayName
dynamic property in object of matlab.graphics.primitive.Line class:
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in matlab.graphics.illustration.Legend/get.String_

Comment: And it returns the plot ith only the first and last legend that I have edited.

Comment: @KaihuaHou How is this a legend problem which you originally asked in the question? If you have a new question, ask it as a new question